# I am trying to return an array of doubles and getting a type mismatch

Tags: java, arrays, double

I am scanning a file of numbers into a datatype double array and am getting a type mismatch for my "score" and "i" variables that i have both already declared doubles.

```
static double[]convert(String file){
        try { 
            
            File ar = new File(file);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            
            double score = 0;
            
        while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            score++;
            sc.nextDouble();    
        }
        double[]stat= new double[score];
         
         
         
         for(double i=0;i<stat.length;i++) {
             stat[i]= sc.nextDouble();
             
         }
return stat;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            return null;}
        }
```

Comment: `return stat;` should not inside `for` loop,also `score` is `double` and can not used to define length of array

Comment: int is the only type allowed for counting in a for loop.You could try long also only based on promotion if the int type is too small capacity. If you are doing all that in main method, after you've fixed that, main does not like much object instantiation code and it's processing and becomes unweildy, throwing errors so best put your processing into methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `return stat;` should be after the for loop not inside it
2. you cannot initialize array with size that can be fraction so `double[] stat = new double[score];` is wrong, you should try `double[] stat = new double[(int)score];` instead or make the variable called `score` of type `int`
3. `stat[i]= sc.nextDouble();` is wrong because you made the variable `i` of type double, so instead of `for(double i=0;i<stat.length;i++)`, you should try `for(int i=0;i<stat.length;i++)` as imagine if the variable `i = 2.5`, there is nothing called `arr[2.5]`.